# $z\rightarrow \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ tansform $0y$ axis into upper semi-circles or rays $x=x_0, y>0$

Tags: complex-analysis, riemannian-geometry

The question origins from  73th page of do Carmo's Riemmanian Geometry. Let $G$ be the upper half-plane of $\mathbb R^2$. Define
$$
z\rightarrow \frac{az+b}{cz+d}, ~~~z=x+iy,~~~ad-bc=1, ~~~a,b,c,d\in \mathbb R
$$
then, how to show the map tansform $0y$ axis into upper semi-circles or rays $x=x_0, y>0$  ?

What I try: since it tansform the $0y$ axis, I can assume $z=it, t>0$. Therefore,
$$
\frac{az+b}{cz+d}=\frac{ati+b}{cti+d} =\frac{bd+ act^2 +it}{c^2t^2+d^2}
$$
return to Euclidean coordinate, I have
$$
x=\frac{bd+ act^2}{c^2t^2+d^2},~~~y=\frac{t}{c^2t^2+d^2}
$$
when $c=0$ it is rays. But when $c\not=0$, it should be  upper semi-circles. Therefore, I should have
$$
(x-x_0)^2 + y^2= C
$$
for some $x_0$ and $C$. There will be three equations, seemly, they can have not solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $d=0$, then one gets $x=\dfrac{bd+ act^2}{c^2t^2+d^2}=\dfrac{a}{c}$ and $y=\dfrac{t}{c^2t^2+d^2}=\dfrac{1}{c^2t}$.

In the following, $d\not=0$.

$x=\dfrac{bd+ act^2}{c^2t^2+d^2}$ can be written as
$$x=\frac{\frac ac(c^2t^2+d^2)+bd-\frac{ad^2}{c}}{c^2t^2+d^2}=\frac ac+\frac{\frac{d(bc-ad)}{c}}{c^2t^2+d^2}=\frac ac+\frac{-d}{c(c^2t^2+d^2)}$$
which implies
$$x-\frac ac=\frac{-d}{c(c^2t^2+d^2)}$$

Therefore, one can obtain
$$\bigg(x-\frac ac\bigg)^2+y^2=\frac{d^2+c^2t^2}{c^2(c^2t^2+d^2)^2}=\frac{1}{c^2(c^2t^2+d^2)}=\frac 1{-cd}\bigg(x-\frac ac\bigg)$$
from which
$$\bigg(x-\frac{2ad-1}{2cd}\bigg)^2+y^2=\bigg(\frac{1}{2cd}\bigg)^2$$
follows.